# Executar comandos ou scripts cmd pelo java não funcionam

Tags: java, cmd

Estou tendo problemas para executar alguns comandos pelo java. Se eu executo eles direto do Netbeans ou executo o projeto diretamente da minha máquina funciona perfeitamente qualquer um dos comandos abaixo:

```
String comando = "cmd /c \"//Server/Sistema/Scripts/executa.bat\"";
exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
```

ou

```
String comando = "cmd /c \"tskill servico\"";
exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
```

Porém como podem perceber o .bat assim como o sistema, ficarão em um servidor na rede e somente o atalho é disponibilizado para o usuário.
Então ao testar em uma máquina do usuário ou o comando não funciona, ou eu tenho que executá-lo varias vezes para que funcione, lembrando que se eu for na pasta do script e executar ele manualmente o mesmo funcionará.

O estranho é que no mesmo botão que chamo o método dessa operação, eu também chamo outro método onde eu abro uma pagina no chrome com o comando:

```
String comando = "cmd /c start chrome.exe http://link";
```

e este funciona perfeitamente, não importa quantas vezes eu clico.

Não sei se isso pode ser algum problema de rede, ou o script/comando quando são executados pelo java, são executados no servidor e não na máquina do usuário onde só existe o atalho. Todos os usuários possuem permissões para a pasta do sistema.

Também tentei usar o comando da seguinte forma:

```
String[] comando = {"\"//Server/Sistema/Scripts/executa.bat\""};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
String.join("& ", comando));
Process p = builder.start();
```

Porém acontece a mesma coisa, direto do Netbeans ele executa, porém pelo jar, tenho que executar várias vezes.

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão agradeço.

Comment: Vou tentar da forma citada nessa pergunta, obrigado!

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi na outra reposta ele faz basicamente a mesma coisa que eu, a única diferença é que ele quer mostrar o retorno. Inclusive já tenho isso aqui. Meu problema também não é executar vários comandos ao mesmo tempo, o problema é não funcionar, ou ter que chamar o mesmo comando várias vezes até que funcione. O que eu possa fazer talvez seria tentar adicionar um loop que caso não tenha funcionado execute o comando novamente, até dar certo..

Comment: Para ser mais exato também executei o comando da seguinte forma: `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                String.join("& ", comando));` como na outra pergunta e não resolveu.

Comment: Qual código está retornando na execução? Qual o retorno de:

exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
exec.waitFor();
int returnValue = exec.exitValue();
System.out.println(returnValue);

Comment: Não retorna nada pois pelo Netbeans o comando: `String comando = "cmd /c \"//Server/Sistema/Scripts/executa.bat\""; exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);exec.waitFor(); int returnValue = exec.exitValue(); System.out.println(returnValue);` funciona normalmente.

Comment: Você disse que criou um atalho, mas ta executando direto o bat.

Cria um atalho e coloca na área de trabalho por exemplo e executa da seguinte forma: String comando = "cmd /c \"C:\\Users\\Diego\\Desktop\\teste.lnk\"";  E roda a tua aplicação como administrador. Dessa forma eu consegui tranquilamente.

Comment: Eu tenho tanto o sistema como os scripts no servidor. Eu criei um atalho do sistema, o .jar. Mas vou testar.

Comment: Acho que consegui resolver o problema, que aparentemente era no  script. Alterei o mesmo para `tasklist | find /i "servico.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (taskkill /f /im "servico.exe"
taskkill /f /im "servico2.exe"
ping -n 2 localhost>nul
)` e funcionou, tanto no Netbeans quanto fora dele apenas com um atalho na máquina do cliente. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema.
A solução encontrada foi alterar o script para:

```
tasklist | find /i "servico.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    taskkill /f /im "servico.exe"
    taskkill /f /im "servico2.exe"
    ping -n 2 localhost>nul
)
```

Dessa forma o script vai buscar se o serviço está rodando, se estiver irá finalizar os 2 serviços que desejo.
A princípio funcionou, não sei porque de outra forma ele não finalizava os serviços pelo sistema, apenas direto pelo Netbeans ou executando o script na mão.
Mas enfim, obrigado pela ajuda!